VSCode Gradle not able to see code files/classpath
Receiving this error:
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip'.
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'McsInnovatorsBaseCode-main-Imported'.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'McsInnovatorsBaseCode-main-Imported'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve edu.wpi.first:GradleRIO:2024.3.1.
Required by:
    project : > edu.wpi.first.GradleRIO:edu.wpi.first.GradleRIO.gradle.plugin:2024.3.1
No matching variant of edu.wpi.first:GradleRIO:2024.3.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.5' but:
  - Variant 'apiElements' capability edu.wpi.first:GradleRIO:2024.3.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
      - Other compatible attribute:
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.5')
  - Variant 'javadocElements' capability edu.wpi.first:GradleRIO:2024.3.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
      - Other compatible attributes:
          - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
          - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.5')
  - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability edu.wpi.first:GradleRIO:2024.3.1 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
      - Other compatible attribute:
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.5')
  - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability edu.wpi.first:GradleRIO:2024.3.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
      - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
      - Other compatible attributes:
          - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
          - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
          - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.5')

I don't really understand what is wrong with the code, and more importantly how to fix it.
Is this user error or does something need updating?
Any input would be appreciated.
There were two errors like the ones above.  Not knowing what they were, I restarted the program to see if a message would appear asking me o import it into a new version or something.  Instead, one of the errors was gone (I didn't change the program)but the other was still there.

"JavaScript is not Java".
